# Kotlin Request location permission at runtime problem

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
import android.Manifest
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
class DeviceScanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Getting BluetoothAdapter from BluetoothManager
    private fun PackageManager.missingSystemFeature(name: String): Boolean = !hasSystemFeature(name)
    private var fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private val locationRequest: LocationRequest =  LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 30
        fastestInterval = 10
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        maxWaitTime= 60
    }

    private var locationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            val locationList = locationResult.locations
            if (locationList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val location = locationList.last()
                Toast.makeText(this@DeviceScanActivity, "Got Location: " + location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG: String = "Log"
        private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99

    }

    private val BluetoothAdapter.isDisabled: Boolean get() = !isEnabled
    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1000


    //On memory
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "DeviceScanActivity()")

        fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        checkLocationPermission()

        packageManager.takeIf {
            it.missingSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
        }?.also {
            Toast.makeText(this, "R.string.ble_not_supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
        bluetoothAdapter?.takeIf { it.isDisabled }?.apply {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        }
        finish()
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            fusedLocationProvider?.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        }
    }

    private fun checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            ) {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton(
                        "OK"
                    ) { _, _ ->
                        //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                        requestLocationPermission()
                    }
                    .create()
                    .show()
            } else {
                requestLocationPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestLocationPermission()")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            )

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "result()")
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        fusedLocationProvider?.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationRequest,
                            locationCallback,
                            Looper.getMainLooper()
                        )
                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

}

To use BLE observing and advertising, I have granted permission at Manifests and also trying to request at runtime manually.

However, my code doesn't look like it is calling onRequestPermissionResult, as it doesn't show "result()" on LogCat, and the advertising/observing is not working properly. What is the problem of my code?

Comment: You cannot request `FINE_LOCATION` and `BACKGROUND_LOCATION` at the same time, this request is automatically declined. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388343/activitycompat-requestpermissions-for-targetsdkversion-30-is-not-working/64388514#64388514

Comment: Even after I eliminate BACKGROUND_LOCATION request, it doesn't look like it is getting the permission, and advertising/observing doesn't work. Do you see any other problem?