# Location Permission Prompt is not showing up

Tags: android, kotlin

`I want to show a permission prompt to get location permission from user.
But my prompt is not showing up in the app.
I have tried many codes from different sites but nothing worked.
Here is my code....

`private fun requestpermission(){

```
    islocationpermissiongranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    backgroundlocationpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    val permissionRequest : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

    if(!islocationpermissiongranted){
        permissionRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    }
    if(!backgroundlocationpermission){
        permissionRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
    }

    if(permissionRequest.isNotEmpty()){
        permissionLauncher.launch(permissionRequest.toTypedArray())
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
        permissions ->
        islocationpermissiongranted = permissions[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] ?: islocationpermissiongranted
        backgroundlocationpermission = permissions[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION] ?: backgroundlocationpermission
    }

    requestpermission()

}`
```

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: You're attempting to requests both foreground and background location permission at the same time. This is not allowed and such requests are implicitly denied. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388343/activitycompat-requestpermissions-for-targetsdkversion-30-is-not-working/64388514#64388514).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to register permission of location in the manifest and if you already added that permission then here is another code and it's work perfectly fine

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = "Location"
        
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@MainActivity,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            1 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ===
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a permission of location in manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
```